# Dynamic navigation with n depth structure using segue iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, segue

I working on an app that will read from a database and use the database to create a navigation structure, which can be of any depth, similar to an organization structure where you may have departments, sections, units etc then employees...
So is this possible using Segue? or I am better with the old xib files?

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you're trying to do. If you're trying to create a controller hierarchy based on data from a database, it will have to be done in code, not with xibs or storyboards (although you could have pre-built views set up in xibs or a storyboard that you use to build this hierarchy in code). Each controller would need to know how to transition to another, have methods and UI elements to carry out this transition,etc., etc. I think this would be very complicated to do.

Comment: the organization structure is exactly what i want to do so assume I have a table like this id,name,type,parent_id where parent_id referes to the same table id, so I don't know during design time how much depth I need to display, for what I've learned from Segue so far is that you define transitions in design time, which is not the case I want, I need to build the navigation based on the data i have